# Why Consumer-driven Contract Test is not working?

Tags: testing, automated-tests

Why CDCT is not working for most cases in real life? The concept and tools have been selled by architects for quite a few years especially in micro-service architect, or in multi-modules complex system, there are a lot of pains for integration testings, but why CDCC is not implemented everywhere?

Answer (score 2):

I heard the concept and tools about CDCT (consumer-driven contract test) about three years ago, I used to do some research in our enterprise software (one of the most complex SaaS softwares in the world, 15 years-old, developed by more than a thousand engineers) and discuss it with our chief arch about two years ago. It looks promising that we are supposed to be able to find a real case to implement it via a proper tool like pact, between two proper teams who have pain point so does the motivation, why not? The concept absolutely makes a lot of sense, the problem it aimed to solve is a very common one (who doesn't have an integration broken by another team?), everything looks perfect and I even added into my yearly goal.

I failed, I was young and simple, it didn't work out, hopeless.

Today I heard a same failure from another team, and no surprise they have same reason that’s why I think it might be write it down to as a reminder and useful (probably) knowledge to share.

The reason is high adoption cost including mindset change. CDCT is not a tool (you can use a tool like pact to better implement it), it's not even a methodology only, it's a new mindset to tell people how to work together.

Yes it’s aimed to solve the problem between multiple systems/modules, but it is more to create a new mindset which needs the two groups of people to accept: firstly a contract is needed (vesus no contract is needed), secondly consumer is the driver of the contract (vesus provider is the driver of integration).

Here is the tricky part, from consumer perspective, what needs to be done for integration point(s):

Before CDCT: 1. find an API and use it. 2. when it breaks, blame provider

After CDCT: 1. find an API 2. drive: find provider, meet with provider, negotiate with provider, come up a contract, repeat this if there is gap, signoff the contract and save it. 3. Write testing, ask provider to review the testing, ask provider to put your testing into their pipeline. Figure out how to make sure provider always make your testing pass rather than comment them out before they release a new version of service.

I can understand why consumer may not really want this, or why they want the result but hesitate to pay the cost first.

So when CDCT implementation will be successful? I think there might be two conditions:

1. The consumer's business is too important to be broken (say accounting), they have no choice but do everything can safeguard the dependency. However, in such a case the better idea is to remove the dependency, or adding duplication and fail-over mechinsim, testing is still the last choice.
2. The provider and consumer are working very closely so the mindset and setup cost will be mininum, unfortunately contract testing might not be needed in this case, because the teams are working very closely.

Regards,
Emil

Comment: Thanks a lot for sharing your experience and findings. Regarding your second point do you think closely collaborating teams can still do consumer driven contract to get confidence in CI/CD ?